# Python: convert list of strings to booleans where boolean is present in string form

Tags: python, replace, boolean

How can I replace `"True"` with the boolean `True` or `1`?

```
mylist = ["Saturday", "True"]
```

I've tried replace, but get the error:

```
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not bool
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Using list comprehension:

```
result = [ True if x == "True" else x for x in mylist  ]
```

**Edited due OP comment**

You can use a dictionary to transform some values:

```
>>> changes = { "True": True,
...             "False": False,
...             "Lemon": "Gin Lemon"
...           }
>>> 
>>> mylist = ["Saturday", "True", "False", "Lemon", "Others" ]
>>> 
>>> [ changes.get( x, x ) for x in mylist ]

['Saturday', True, False, 'Gin Lemon', 'Others']
```

The tip is to use [python dictionary `get` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)  with a default value:

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

Comment: Or use `x == 'True' or x`. I tend to balk at the sight of boolean literals in a conditional expression..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, nice shot! Your approach is shortest and readable.

Comment: And how can i extend this list comprehension if i have both "True", "Saturday" and "False" and wish to convert to True, "Saturday" and False

Comment: @fashioncoder: then it's `x == 'True' if x in {'True', 'False'} else x`.

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters or: result = [ True if x == "True" else False if x == 'False' else x for x in mylist  ]

Comment: @fashioncoder, I just edited my answer.

Comment: Very nice solution @daniherrera